# Compilation first rule

Tags: eclipse, maven, sonarqube

I downloaded the project `1_ MyFirst Custom Check`. I've imported it into eclipse as a `Maven` project.

Using `maven install` I received the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/sonar-packaging-maven-plugin/sonar-packaging-maven-plugin/1.15/sonar-packaging-maven-plugin-1.15.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.15 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:jar:1.15 @
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: sonar-plugin @ line 9, column 14
@ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] The project org.sonar.samples:java-custom-rules-template:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\rmolano\Downloads\sonar-examples-master\plugins\tutorial\java-custom-rules-template\completed\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.15 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:jar:1.15: Could not transfer artifact org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:pom:1.15 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: sonar-plugin @ line 9, column 14
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

The truth that can not be put in the `settings.xml` in maven repo `l .m2` folder, I tested with the following:

```
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>sonar</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        <sonar.host.url>
          http://localhost:9000
        </sonar.host.url>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>sonar</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

`Sonarquebe` installation is with the embedded database.
 
How I can make it compile? What would be the configuration settings for me down dependencies correctly?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: yes. it was that . Thanks